# CheckOut page programaticlly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, check-out

Im trying to remove all content in page.
but i get an exception when i trying to do this, it says that the file is not checked out and i have to do this. And wehn i use     file.CheckOut()
i see that the file is checked out to the systemAcount and i get exception that the file is CheckedOut to another user

How to do that i can ignore the outcheck, or CheckOut to the current/specific user

```
        var webMngr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Sidor/default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart> webPartList = (from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart in webMngr.WebParts

                                                                        select webPart).ToList();
        SPFile file = web.GetFile(web.Url+"Sidor/default.aspx");
        //file.CheckOut();
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;


        object _lock = new object();

        lock (_lock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < webMngr.WebParts.Count; i++)
            {
                webMngr.DeleteWebPart(webPartList[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should elevate the permission and checkin the file, then checkout and delete.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    var webMngr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Sidor/default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
    List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart> webPartList = (from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart in webMngr.WebParts select webPart).ToList();
    SPFile file = web.GetFile(web.Url+"Sidor/default.aspx");

    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    if (file.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.Online)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
        file.CheckIn("Comment");
    }  
    file.CheckOut();

    object _lock = new object();

    lock (_lock)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < webMngr.WebParts.Count; i++)
        {
            webMngr.DeleteWebPart(webPartList[i]);
        }
    }
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
});
```

Comment: didnt hepl, Got the same exception "the file is ouchecked to another user"

Im logged in to the windows as Admin, and when i checkout the file i se that the file is checkedout to the FarmAdmin/SystemAcount.

Comment: Can you remove the lock and check?

Comment: Still the same exception

Comment: From where this code is getting executed, webpart or console application or event receiver?

Comment: im running this from webpart on sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

If you have administrative rights, it is possible to override the check-out via the View All Site Content page:

1. Site Actions
2. View All Site Content
3. Pages
4. Hover the item you want to check out, and from the context-menu (arrow-down next to the filename), choose "Discard Check Out"

It is also possible to perform this routine through SharePoint Designer.

Another option could be to use UndoCheckOut:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.undocheckout.aspx